# Is it true that $0\in 1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms, peano-axioms

From Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory and Peano axioms, we have $0=\varnothing$ and $1=\varnothing\cup{\{\varnothing\}}\implies0\in 1$.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Why isn't this obvious?

Comment: It's true, in the context of this definition.

Comment: It is in the von Neumann definition of the ordinals. From Peano's axioms it doesn't follow.

Comment: I will just add that if you use [von Neumann definition of ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals), then $\alpha<\beta$, $\alpha\in\beta$ and $\alpha\subsetneq\beta$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, $0\in1$, since $0=\emptyset$ and $1=\{\emptyset\}$. On the other hand, you are wrong when you assert that Peano axioms assert that $0=\emptyset$ and $1=\{\emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 3):

It goes like this:

- $0=\emptyset $
- $n+1=n \cup\{n\}$

So $n=\{0,1,...,n-1\}$.

So $$m \leq n \implies m \subseteq n$$
$$m<n \implies m \in n$$